# src folder not included in exported .jar messing up resource paths (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, path, src

So I have a project that runs perfectly within Eclipse, but when I export it as a runnable .jar the paths to my .png resource files won't work anymore as the src folder is not included in the exported .jar.

```
createTexture("resources/grass.png", 0);
```

This is where I use the path.

```
public static void createTexture(String path, int index){
    try (InputStream inputStream = Drawer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path)){
        textureDecoder = new PNGDecoder(inputStream); [...]
```

now I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.matthiasmann.twl.utils.PNGDecoder.readFully(PNGDecoder.java:802)
at de.matthiasmann.twl.utils.PNGDecoder.<init>(PNGDecoder.java:112)
at workers.Drawer.createTexture(Drawer.java:80)
at workers.Drawer.openglSetup(Drawer.java:44)
at jonta.Main.setUp(Main.java:41)
at jonta.Main.main(Main.java:121)
```

**OLD:**
This is obviously the error I get when I try to run the .jar:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\resources\grass.png
```

*I'll of course include more code/configurations I've made if that would be relevant.*

EDIT: Problem solved, thanks!

Comment: Objects in a jar are not files and cannot be accessed using File APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
InputStream inputStream = className.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
```

Comment: I get that I cannot use _this_ in a static context

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, after selecting "Export ..." and "JAR File", there is checkbox for "Export Java source files and resources". You need to click that checkbox.

Comment: Did not change anything